# Getting around JSONDecodeError when JSON seems fine

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to execute the script below and am getting a JSONDecodeError, which is causing my while loop to run away with errors.

```
import csv
import json
import time
import requests

page_count = 1000
price_inc = 10
counter = 0
api_response = None
str_json = None

price = 227
while price <= 1300:
    try:
         url = 'https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=' + str(counter) + '&pageSize=' + str(page_count) + '&minPrice=' + str(price) + '&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_='
         s = requests.session()
         api_response  = s.get(url, allow_redirects=True).json()
         str_json = json.dumps(api_response)
         print(price)
         price = price + price_inc
         s.close()
         time.sleep(2)
    except ValueError:
         print('error')
         print(price)
         price = price + price_inc
         time.sleep(1)
```

I added `time.sleep()` because I was running into buffering errors.  The code will run about 5-6 iterations before a JSONDecodeError is raised, then the loop will raise nothing but errors until it is manually stopped or the loop finishes.  I've searched and tried what I can find on stackoverflow, but have not found a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I can't run your code because `counter` is not defined. What should it be?

Comment: I apologize.  `counter = 0`

Comment: When the decode fails, it is because the page responded with an error message saying `Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.<br/>
Please try again later.`. It may be due to rate limiting on the server side, but I am not sure.

Comment: Would a longer time delay between requests normally get around that?

Comment: I am not sure. It may have nothing to do with rate-limiting at all. You could try it and see. Sorry, I can't help much more than that.